# How does Vue router-link get its parameters?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have vue router config with routes like this:

```
{
    path: '/:language/:url/filter/',
    name: 'search-filter',
    component: SearchFilter,
    meta: { removeScroll: true }
}
{
    path: '/:language/:url/map/',
    name: 'search-map',
    component: SearchMap,
    meta: { removeScroll: true }
}
```

Whenever I place a `router-link` with that component like so:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'search-map' }">
    <svg-inline name="beacon-circle"></svg-inline>
    {{ trans.hotel.show_map }}
</router-link>
```

It generates a full route to the named route of `search-map`. Now I have not manually passed in parameters to the `<router-link>`. It seem to grab the route parameters from the current component to generate the route parameters for the named route url.

I can not find anything about this in the Vue.js documentation about the fact that this is being done automatically.

If I inspect the `router-link` component with the Vue devtools it does have a `props` object which contains a `to` object which holds the parameters. I can't seem to find any documentation on this though.

Comment: Well, you're using dynamic segments in the path (`:language` and `:url`, so what's confusing about the router-link component having parameters in the props?

Comment: @BennettDams This is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation what I have read seems to imply you need to manually pass in the parameters to set up the named route in the `router-link`.

Comment: "A dynamic segment is denoted by a colon :. When a route is matched, the value of the dynamic segments will be exposed as this.$route.params in every component." https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching

Comment: An optional parameter that which is being set will not be passed though. It will be set on the direct component which is related to my `component` property on the route. It will however not be passed on to `router-link` components. This is what I need. This is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: It can't find it in the doc either. But the logic can be found in `normalizeLocation` function in https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/27ced4312e7b0646cabab3311c6ae15960a27bb1/src/util/location.js